# Are the Mystics ever clearly depicted as having four hands?

Tags: movie, dark-crystal

Having watched *The Dark Crystal* at a young age, I grew up thinking that the Mystics had three arms. However [this source](http://www.darkcrystal.com/encyclopedia_urru.php) says that they have four.

I know they used puppetry for all of the creatures in *The Dark Crystal*, so that created some limitations in what they were able to depict. Were there any shots in the film that clearly depicted the Mystics as having four arms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see a Mystic's **four** hands in the sequence below, at timestamp 0:12

[image]

and within the first few seconds of the film starting, just after the opening scene with the Skeksis

[image]

and again in the sequence, just before they send the gelfling off on his quest

[image]

Comment: The first three aren't very clear, esp. #3, but it is pretty clear in #4. Thanks!

Comment: One of the mystics actually does have only the three hands; he is missing one, like his skeksis counterpart.

Comment: @Buzz which one?

Comment: It's UrTih, the alchemist.  His only notable role in the story is that he is the one that winks out of existence when his other half, SkekTek the scientist, dies.  So a viewer would be highly unlikely to spot the artificial limb unless they were looking for it.  (SkekTek's metal arm is obviously much more prominent.)

Comment: And if you want a closer look, urSol the Chanter was donated to the Pittsburgh Children's Museum, and is on display (https://pittsburgh.verylocal.com/jim-hensons-mysterious-gift-to-pittsburgh-ursol-the-chanter/55698/)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Cheers for that

Answer (score 5):

Following up on my comment above about [urSol the Chanter being at the Children's Museum of Pittsburgh](https://pittsburgh.verylocal.com/jim-hensons-mysterious-gift-to-pittsburgh-ursol-the-chanter/55698/), we were visiting the museum today. The puppet was not on public display, but one of the workers brought us down to view it. Behold, four hands:

[image: urSol the Chanter, left side] [image: urSol the Chanter, right side]